# Disabling Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, angularjs-config

I'm trying to **disable** SCE in AngularJS. 
According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) this is what needs to be done:

```
angular.module('myAppWithSceDisabledmyApp', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
  // Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
  // Do not use in new projects.
  $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

This is my app.config.js:

```
angular.module('yapoApp').config(['$sceProvider', '$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',  '$httpProvider',
    function config($sceProvider, $locationProvider, $routeProvider,  $httpProvider) {

        // disable SCE completely (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)
        $sceProvider.enabled(false);

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $routeProvider.when('/actors', {
            template: '<actor-list></actor-list>'
        }).when('/actors/:actorId', {
            template: '<actor-detail></actor-detail>'
        }).when('/movies/', {
            template: '<movie-list></movie-list>'
        }).when('/movies/:movieId', {
            template: '<movie-detail></movie-detail>'
        }).otherwise('/'), {
            template: '<br><br><br><br><h1> This is temp index</h1>'

        };


    }

]);
```

And I'm still getting an error:

> [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: /static/movies/{{
>   $ctrl.movie.id }}/sample/sample.mp4 Strict Contextual Escaping
>   disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a
>   trusted value is required.

The html template causing the error:

```
 <video width="{{ $ctrl.videoWidth }}px" controls>
        <source ng-src="/static/movies/{{ $ctrl.movie.id }}/sample/sample.mp4">

        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

I feel like I'm missing some simple syntax error. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check this, from [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#can-i-disable-sce-completely-):

> ## Can I disable SCE completely?
>
> Yes, you can. However, this is strongly discouraged. SCE gives you a lot of security benefits for little coding overhead. It will be much harder to take an SCE disabled application and either secure it on your own or enable SCE at a later stage. It might make sense to disable SCE for cases where you have a lot of existing code that was written before SCE was introduced and you're migrating them a module at a time.

Well, I don't think you need to disable **SCE** in this case, and also, for example, if you use `ngBindHtml` to render some HTML, AngularJS will throw an error unless the scope variable assigned to `ngBindHtml` is wrapped with `$sce.trustAsHtml`.

But, let's back to the *error*, which one speaks for itself:

> Error while interpolating: /static/movies/{{ $ctrl.movie.id
>   }}/sample/sample.mp4

You just need to concatenate it in the right way, like this:

```
<source ng-src="{{'/static/movies/' + $ctrl.movie.id + '/sample/sample.mp4'}}">
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason, this doesn't work. "{{'/static/movies/' + $ctrl.movie.id + '/sample/sample.mp4'}} trying to look for the sample.mp4 in /static/movies//sample/sample.mp4. Outside of the Source filed it works fine (Outputs /static/movies/12/sample/sample.mp4) Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352). Apparently, it's not an SCE issue. It's an issue with how Angular gets along with Html5 Video "source: tag.

If there is only one video source, having the HTML look like this:

```
<video src="ng-src="{{'/static/movies/' + $ctrl.movie.id +  '/sample/sample.mp4'}}" width="{{ $ctrl.videoWidth }}px" controls>    
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Instead of this:

```
<video width="{{ $ctrl.videoWidth }}px" controls>
        <source ng-src="{{'/static/movies/' + $ctrl.movie.id +  '/sample/sample.mp4'}}">

        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Solves the problem.

Of course, @developer033 was correct, and my initial concatenation was wrong.